# How to accomplish a task like this in Java using scanner and array

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

-Prompt the user to enter a list of strings.  This could be a list of names, cities, sports teams, etc.  The user can enter the list of words in one list, or individually after pressing enter after each entry.
-Parse the list of strings into an array.  (There are two primary ways you can design this, either using a for loop, with the user entering one word at a time,  or by splitting the entire list in one step.)
-Prompt the user to enter the word to search for.  (Example; Seattle, or Seahawks, or Canada, etc)
-The program should search the array for the search word, and determine if the search word exists in the array.  If the word exists more than once, it should produce a count of the number of times it exists.
-The program will then output the list of words, the search word, whether the search word exists in the list (yes or no), and if it does exist, how many times it is found in the list.

Comment: Where exactly are you having difficulty carrying out this task?

Comment: Just this is my first cs class project. I learned java in textbook, but to actual use it, I am quite confused how to start.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have no code provided, I can only give you an idea as of now. Using a scanner, the user enters the cities, then you need to call an array library. To count how many cities were on the list as entered by the user, use `int counter = 0;` and for each time set it to `counter++;` after each condition. In the end, you have to make it `counter--:` to stop the counter for counting the number of cities if they exist in the array list. You can also call `array.list();` for listing the cities.

Comment: Ok, I will start with that. Thank you!